# Ruby on Rails include a javascript from an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action `common/location`

```
#encoding: utf-8 
class CommonController < ApplicationController
  def location
    @locations=Location.select(['`key`','name','parent'])
    render json: @locations
  end
end
```

I want to include this js through:

```
=javascript_include_tag "common/location"
```

but this dosen't work!

So I want to know how to include a js from an ation.

Comment: Is it json, not javascript? Even if you could include it like that, what good would it be?

Comment: javascript_include_tag is used to include a javascript file, not to render json code in your views.

Comment: =javascript_include_tag url_for(action:'location',controller:'common')

Comment: you are right,I get the js from an ajax get request,and assignment the data to an variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your locations in javascript you can do several things:

- Use gon
- write javascript code in your view
- use ajax to fetch your locations (http://yourhost.com/common/location.js)
- use html5 data attributes to set your locations in the views
- probably other ways

Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript